# Перезагрузка компонента в Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Этот вопрос задавался не раз. Но возможно в конкретном случае его можно решить как-то иначе.

Есть компонент toolbar c переключателем прав пользователя. Есть router-view со всякими таблицами. При переключении прав мне нужно перезагрузить данные в таблицу. Выполнить бы mounted() ещё раз...

Переход по `this.$router.go()` перезагружает страницу полностью но и решает все проблемы. Хотелось бы перезагрузить только вью.

Повесить watch на $route во всех файлах тоже вариант, но не слишком расширяемо - нужно следить за всеми вьюхами проекта.

Comment: т.е. нужно чтобы перемонтировало все что в router-view?

Comment: да. корневой элемент хотяб. Дочерние элементы ничего не загружают.

Comment: кей повесить на роутер-вью... попробую завтра

Comment: Как раз на этот вариант наткнулся) работает, кстати

Comment: @NikitaUmnov у меня не сработал в том варианте что наткнуля. Попробую в кей записать какой-то хэш из переменных на тулбаре

Comment: Я просто число инкриментировал, в дочерних срабатывал mounted каждый раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше решение это использование `key` на компоненте. Вот простой пример. В консоле видно как компонент создается при каждом изменении `role`.

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
    name: "Child",
    template: "#child",
    props: ['role'],
    mounted () {
     console.log("Компонент был создан заново!")
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        role: 'user'
    },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Я:
    <label>
        <input type="radio" v-model="role" value="admin">
        Администратор
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" v-model="role" value="user">
        Пользователь
    </label>
    <Child :role="role" :key="role"></Child>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="child">
 <h1>Я компонент с правами: {{ role }}</h1>
</script>
```